# Neumann boundary condition in spherical coordinates

Tags: boundary-conditions, eigenvalue, spherical-harmonics, heat-conduction

I'm trying to solve heat equation
$$\nabla^2 u = \frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$
in the region
$$
a \leq r \leq b, \ \ \ \ 0 \leq \varphi \leq 2\pi, \ \ \ \ 0 \leq \theta \leq \theta_0
$$
with $\theta_0$ a fixed number, with boundary conditions
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 0 \ \ \ \ in \ \ r=a, r=b
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} = 0 \ \ \ \ in \ \ \theta = \theta_0
$$

I have trouble finding the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues associated to $\theta$. Are they the Legendre polynomials? And if they aren't, is it possible to find them analytically?

**-- Update --**

Firstly, I separed the temporal part from the spatial one, $u = T(t) \phi(r,\theta,\varphi)$, obtaining:
$$
\begin{gather}
T'' = -\lambda T \\
\nabla^2 \phi = -\lambda \phi
\end{gather}
$$

Next, I separed again the spatial function $\phi$ into three parts, each one corresponding to each spherical coordinate:
$$
\phi = F(\varphi)R(r)G(\theta)
$$

- If we apply periodic conditions to $F$ ($u(\varphi=-\pi) = u(\varphi=\pi)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \varphi} (\varphi=-\pi) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \varphi} (\varphi=\pi)$, the eigenfunctions associated to $\varphi$ are
  $$
  \cos(m\varphi), \ \ \sin(m\varphi)
  $$

with $m$ a non-negative integer.

- Eigenfunctions associated to radial part $R$ are
  $$
  \frac{J_{n+1/2} (\sqrt{\lambda}r)}{\sqrt{r}}, \ \ \frac{Y_{n+1/2} (\sqrt{\lambda}r)}{\sqrt{r}}
  $$

with $J_k$ and $Y_k$ Bessel functions of order $k$ of first and second kind, respectively. We should apply Neumann conditions in $r=a$ and $r=b$.

My doubts arrive when dealing with $G$. We need $G$ to be bounded at $\theta = 0$ and also to verify Neumann condition at $\theta = \theta_0$. So I thought we would need Legendre polynomials (or, at least, Legendre associated functions).

Comment: Please show us what work you've done to solve the problem. It's no good guessing whether there are Legendre polynomials involved (there aren't). And yes: an analytical solution does exist.

Comment: You'll also need an *initial condition*.

Comment: I know an initial condition is needed, but I omitted it for now.

Comment: I edited my question in order to explain better what I did. Thank you very much.

Comment: Much better but have you developed $G(\theta)$?

Comment: You're probably right about the Legendre's, see here: http://chemeng.iisc.ac.in/kumaran/courses/chap5.pdf (P.2, on $\Theta(\theta)$).

Comment: I supposed G had to follow the form:  $$G(\theta) = C_1 P_n^m (cos \theta) + C_2 Q_n^m (cos \theta)$$, as in the text is said. Only $P_n^m$ is bounded at $\theta = 0$ (I understood), but when deriving it to apply the boundary condition... We should find a relationship between $n$ and $m$, shouldn't we?

Comment: *We should find a relationship between n and m, shouldn't we?* Of course but to find it you need to carry out the whole derivation, step by step.

Comment: I also believe you can drop the $\sin(m\varphi)$, see here: http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=19#pid453116

Comment: Applying a formula found here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20070412093658/http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/SphericalHarmonics.pdf

I reach the following relationship:
$$
\frac{(P_n (\cos \theta_0))^{m)}}{(P_{n-1} (\cos \theta=0))^{m)}} = \frac{n+m}{n \cos \theta_0}
$$

where $f^{m)}$ denotes the m-th derivative of $f$.